# Dart extension - The method 'xxx' isn't defined for the type 'xxx'

Tags: flutter, dart

I've made this extension on an enumm which has a static function `toSelectList()`, but when I try to use the extension, the `toSelectList()` is not recognised. I have had this issue before in VSCode, so I understand the IDE may sometimes show a warning, but the warning should go away and this time it isn't. The only fix that has worked is to use the extension and not use the original enum being extended. My code:

The enum and extension (`grocery_item_categories_enum.dart`):

```
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/widgets/form_widgets/select/common/card_select_list_item/card_select_list_item.dart';

enum GroceryItemCategoryEnum {
  meat,
  dairy,
  baking,
  condiments,
  cooking,
  confectionary,
  dessert,
  healthFood,
}

extension GroceryItemCategoryExtension on GroceryItemCategoryEnum {
  static const items = {
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.meat:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Meat', id: 1, iconCodePoint: 0xf814),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.dairy:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Dairy', id: 2, iconCodePoint: 0xf7f0),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.baking:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Baking', id: 3, iconCodePoint: 0xf563),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.condiments:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Condiments', id: 4, iconCodePoint: 0xf72f),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.cooking:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Cooking', id: 5, iconCodePoint: 0xe01d),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.confectionary: CardSelectListItem(
        label: 'Confectionary', id: 6, iconCodePoint: 0xf819),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.dessert:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Dessert', id: 7, iconCodePoint: 0xf810),
    GroceryItemCategoryEnum.healthFood:
        CardSelectListItem(label: 'Health Food', id: 8, iconCodePoint: 0xf787),
  };

  CardSelectListItem get item => items[this];

  static List<CardSelectListItem> toSelectList() {
    return const [
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Meat', id: 1, iconCodePoint: 0xf814),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Dairy', id: 2, iconCodePoint: 0xf7f0),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Baking', id: 3, iconCodePoint: 0xf563),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Condiments', id: 4, iconCodePoint: 0xf72f),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Cooking', id: 5, iconCodePoint: 0xe01d),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Confectionary', id: 6, iconCodePoint: 0xf819),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Dessert', id: 7, iconCodePoint: 0xf810),
      CardSelectListItem(label: 'Health Food', id: 8, iconCodePoint: 0xf787),
    ];
  }
}
```

Trying to use it:

```
import 'package:vepo/src/domain/constants/grocery_item_categories_enum.dart';

  @override
  List<Widget> createItemCategoriesFormWidgets({BuildContext context}) {
    return [
      VpSelectMultipleCards(listItems: GroceryItemCategoryEnum.toSelectList())
    ];
  }
```

compile time error:

```
The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<CardSelectListItem>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
The method 'toSelectList' isn't defined for the type 'GroceryItemCategoryEnum'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toSelectList'.dart(undefined_method)
```

How do I use this extension method `toSelectList()` without the IDE showing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare static methods in an extension, but they are static on the extension itself.

You should therefore call `toSelectList()` on `GroceryItemCategoryExtension` and not on `GroceryItemCategory`.

Basic example on `String`:

```
void main() {
  // print(String.getMyString());
  // The method 'getMyString' isn't defined for the type 'String' 
  print(StringX.getMyString());
}

extension StringX on String {
  static String getMyString() => "MyString"; 
}
```

Comment: To clarify: an extension adds syntactic sugar to *instances* of the type to extend, so `GroceryItemCategoryEnum.meat.toSelectList()` should work.  If you want to invoke it with a *type*, then you can just invoke the extension directly (`GroceryItemCategoryExtension.toSelectList()`).  Of course, if you do that, there's not much point to making it an extension instead of a freestanding function.